# How to load Web view in different View in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, webview

I have an textfield which the user types whatever thing they want to Google. When the user clicks done in the Textfield it goes to a new view with an web view. The **ISSUE** Is when I type something in the textfield the web view is just white (Doesn't load it to the web view).

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *query = [self buildGoogleSearchParameter:self.searchField];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co/search?q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];


}

- (NSString *)buildGoogleSearchParameter:(NSString *)searchField
{
    NSArray *unencodedStrings = [searchField componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *encodedStrings = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *unencodedString in unencodedStrings)
        [encodedStrings addObject:[self urlEncode:unencodedString]];

    return [encodedStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];
}

- (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)unencodedString
{
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}


-(IBAction)searchdone {

    ViewController *web = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
    web.searchField = searchbar.text;
    [self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you appear to be trying to issue `loadRequest` before you even create the controller with a storyboard identifier of `"WebView"`.

If you're trying to present a new modal view with the `UIWebView` on it, generally, you would add a `NSString` property in your web view `ViewController` for the string being searched, say `searchField`, e.g.:

```
-(IBAction)searchdone {

    ViewController *web = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
    web.searchField = searchbar.text;
    [self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];
}
```

and then the `viewDidLoad` for that view controller with the web view would then do the `loadRequest` building the URL using the `searchField` property:

Thus, `ViewController.h` for the destination view controller might have an `@interface` that includes not only the `UIWebView`, but also our new `searchField` property:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchField;

@end
```

And the `@implementation` in the .m file might be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *query = [self buildGoogleSearchParameter:self.searchField];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co/search?q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (NSString *)buildGoogleSearchParameter:(NSString *)searchField
{
    NSArray *unencodedStrings = [searchField componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *encodedStrings = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *unencodedString in unencodedStrings)
        [encodedStrings addObject:[self urlEncode:unencodedString]];

    return [encodedStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];
}

- (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)unencodedString
{
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Note, `webView` is the name for my `IBOutlet` for my `UIWebView`. You should replace that with whatever is appropriate for your project.

Also notice that I did some url encoding of the search fields. That way you can search for fields with ampersand characters, quotation marks, etc. The easiest way to do that is the `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` that you see above.

Comment: Could you combine my code with your code (I think i am doing it wrong)?

Comment: their is an issue. When every i type anything in the textfiled it goes to google homepage :(

Comment: @iProgrammed sounds like you're not setting `web.searchField` properly. You might want to NSLog the searchbar.text and make sure you're grabbing the search text properly.

Comment: I got (null) in NSLog(@"%@",searchbar);

Comment: Fixed the Issue I forgot to add searchbar.text in mainstoryboard :)

Comment: @iProgrammed I gather that your view controller is pushing to another instance of itself when you're loading a page. You can do that if you want, but it's unnecessary, uses up memory, and you lose some built-in `UIWebView` functionality. Your search can do another `loadRequest` on the existing `UIWebView` (without creating another instance of the controller). And when you want to go back, you can use the `UIWebView` method `goBack` and you're right there at the previous page. And if you do that, you can also do `goForward` to automatically return to the web page you did `goBack` from.

Comment: I am creating an Yahoo engine with also the Google. So in my view thereof are two different button one for Google one for Yahoo. If the user clicks the Yahoo one how can I load the webview to Yahoo search. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: I have two buttons one for Google one for Yahoo. When the user clicks Yahoo how can I change URL to Yahoo Search. Thanks So Much.

Comment: @iProgrammed Right now, you're setting a property for the `searchField` right? Just add another property for the Google v. API. Then the `IBAction` for those two buttons would set that property accordingly. And obviously change `viewDidLoad` to then check that property and build the URL accordingly. Basically, everything you did for passing and using `searchField`, you now repeat for this new "google" vs "yahoo" field.

Comment: Thanks do you Know the Yahoo Search URL.

Comment: No Problem, I will "Google" it.